# Can I control the permissions of pre-installed "system apps" in Android Marshmallow?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I am *really* excited for the [permission control](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6270602?hl=en) feature available in Android M. I am considering buying a phone that supports this OS just for that one feature.

However, I am concerned if I will be able to control permissions on the "stock apps" without rooting or flashing my device with a new ROM? Even a Nexus will come with stuff like Google Maps, I am sure. So will I be able to control what Google Maps has access to, for example? What about Samsung devices and the egregious bloatmalware they package with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using apps which require certain permissions for the first time, the app asks you to grant the permission, which happens with stock apps too. If it doesn't, then permissions for stock apps can be managed in the App Permissions section of the Settings.

Comment: That sounds great! Can you please confirm this with a device and an example?

Comment: I'm using the Nexus 6P and just disabled the camera permission to the stock app to confirm :p

Comment: That is indeed awesome

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can surely do it starting from Android 6.0. I even played with it trying to download a file from my browser after refusing it storage access and it expectedly crashed. So yes, you can.

Comment: How would you like to justify the existence of your answer given that [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/131460/96277) already covers your answer's content?

Comment: So that means I shouldn't have posted this answer?